# Image is not visible of user added buttons in active report 6.0

Tags: c#-4.0, activereports

I have a winform application. In this application I am using active reports for reporting purpose. So in active report viewer I have added some buttons like Print, Export and Email. I am attaching a snapshot where I am adding these buttons.

[image]

And here is some code for how I am adding these buttons on Load event.

Code

My problem is that how to show image with these buttons in active reports as shown in attached image.

Comment: This question announced the addition of code, and then adds the word "Code" in its place. I think it is therefore not a full demonstration of the problem, and can be put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code used by you is not displayed in the posted query, however, following is the code snippet that can be used to add a custom button in the Viewer Toolbar along with the desired image:

```
Dim prnt_btn As New ToolStripButton
prnt_btn.Image = Image.FromFile("..\..\Print.jpg")
Viewer1.Toolbar.ToolStrip.Items.Insert(2, prnt_btn)
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting C# code and Thanks Mohita. I have implement some other code for displaying image with text. That is most of similar of your given code.

Answer (score 0):

We can add this code for displaying the image with text in active report viewer. Use this code on Load event of viewer.

```
 viewer1.Toolbar.Images.Images.Add("myIcon",Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\\icon.bmp")); 

  int myIcon = viewer1.Toolbar.Images.Images.IndexOfKey("myIcon"); 

  DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.Button btn = new DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.Button(); 

  btn.ButtonStyle = DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Toolbar.ButtonStyle.TextAndIcon; 

  btn.ImageIndex = myIcon;
```